# How to remove an old pip version link with python homebrew?

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

I am running Mac OSX 12.4 and have Python 3.10.4 installed. All other Python versions were removed.

It seems that I previously installed pip for different versions of Python, i.e., one pip installation for Python 3.9 and another for Python 3.10.

Running the command `pip -V` in the terminal prints:

```
zsh: /opt/homebrew/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9: no such file or directory
pip 22.1.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
```

I would like to clean up my installations a bit and therefore ask how can I remove the old link of pip to Python 3.9, which does no longer exist? Is there a straightforward command here?

Comment: `brew doctor` may help find these remaining Python 3.9 programs that won't work anymore, and advice on how to get rid of them. Alternatively, it would seem that you can just nuke the whole `/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/` directory (probably by renaming it to e.g. `/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9_aside/`, and completely remove that if everything still runs smoothly after a month or so.

Comment: How did you install Pip? Or did it come with Homebrew Python? (In which case, there should also be one for 3.10.)

Comment: Also an option is to try and upgrade/reinstall Pip: `python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip`. I've never forced a reinstall for Pip itself, but it may work. The `python -m pip` part will ensure you're using the correct Pip version for the standard (3.10) Python version.

Comment: Thanks. ```Brew doctor```: there are no dependencies etc. for Python 3.9 left. I deleted the folder path ```/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/``` a while ago already. Python 3.9 does also not appear in ```brew list```.  I now also ran ```python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip``` but the old pip linkage with Python 3.9 still remains. I think that I installed pip via the terminal command ```python get-pip.py``` but I am not sure anymore.

Comment: Then just remove `/opt/homebrew/bin/pip`. You could also edit it to use the correct interpreter, but removing it seems better. You will need to re-install Pip, but see if you can do that through Homebrew: installing software in your package-manager directories without using the package manager is generally cause for problems.

Comment: Thank you! Removing ```/opt/homebrew/bin/pip```solved it.

Comment: Where is the new Pip (3.10) located now?

Comment: Pip for Python 3.10 is now (or still) located in ```/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip```. I also reinstalled it as per your suggestion, namely via using the command ```python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip```.

Comment: Hm, also a bit dangerous, since it's in a system path. It'll be okay, but if you're the only user, it may be better/safer to simply not use `sudo`. Pip will then install things (including itself) automatically in `~/.local/bin`, which you can add to `PATH`.